# Apache Beam trigger a pane after equal number of elements

Tags: java, apache-beam

we use a Apache Beam to send some data to the API. API accepts only certain amount of elements for single API call.

To group elements into micro batches we used mixed trigger which fires when one of the condition occurs: 1) after 30 seconds 2) when at least 10 elements will be gathered.

Now it seems, that for some cases triggers passes more than 10 elements for a single pane. Any suggestion to force an exact number of record? I suppose, that as the method names suggests '.elementsCountAtLeast(int x)`more then`x` elements can be passed.

```
// definition
public class WindowHelper {

    public static Window<KV<String,String>> generateWIndow() {
        Window <KV<String,String>> window = Window.<KV<String,String>>into(
            new GlobalWindows()).triggering(
                Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(
                    AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(10),
                    AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(30))))
    ).discardingFiredPanes();

    }
}

// invocation
data.apply(WindowHelper.generateWindow())

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go back to thinking about why you want this, to decide between two options:

- You *cannot* use triggers to get an exact number of elements, by design: To achieve efficiency, Beam runners amortize costs by processing bundles of elements together. This is not just for batch, but also for streaming. So triggers say "OK it is time to output" but the runner is always allowed to wait until a "good" time. This is usually at the end of processing a bundle, when all the data will be flushed.
- You *can* use [`GroupIntoBatches`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/aggregation/groupintobatches/) to get batches of *less than or equal* to 10 elements. The last batch may be small and be flushed with less than 10.

Now, in stream processing you may often go back and reprocess older data to fix bugs or run experiments. You should think about this to help you decide.

**Important**:

- For `GroupIntoBatches` the size of the batches is part of the input/output specification. You will get batches of 10 elements or less in both streaming and batch scenarios.
- For triggers, it is *only* a control for balancing cost/latency/completeness of results. In this case, a runner will probably produce *huge* bundles and trigger only at the end.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I did not mentioned that we are operating with streaming pipeline. We consider to use GroupIntoBatches.

Comment: No worries. I guessed that you were running a streaming pipeline. Everything is designed to also work for batch, since 90% of streaming use cases also involve backfill, bugfixes, reprocessing, experiments, etc.